# How can I draw a bitmap rotated in wxPython?

Tags: graphics, wxpython

How do I draw a bitmap to a DC, while rotating it by a specified angle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Al - he deserves the answer, but this (admittedly untested) code fragment should do what you asked for:

```
def write_bmp_to_dc_rotated( dc, bitmap, angle ):
    '''
    Rotate a bitmap and write it to the supplied device context.
    '''
    img = bitmap.ConvertToImage()
    img_centre = wx.Point( img.GetWidth()/2, img.GetHeight()/2 )
    img = img.Rotate( angle, img_centre )
    dc.WriteBitmap( img.ConvertToBitmap(), 0, 0 )
```

One thing to note though from [the docs](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/2.6/wx_wxbitmapoverview.html#wxbitmapoverview):

> ...using wxImage is the preferred way to load images in wxWidgets, with the exception of resources...

Was there a particular reason to load it as a bitmap rather than a wx.Image?

Comment: I need to draw it to the screen, and the wx.Image doc says I'll need to convert it to bitmap before I could draw it.

Comment: Can you either post the fixed result yourself or suggest what you did to fix the above to improve the example?

Comment: I ended up doing it with a GraphicsContext, similar to what Anurag suggested.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this is the best way of doing it, but one option would be to convert it to a wx.Image with [ConvertToImage](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Bitmap-class.html#ConvertToImage) ([wxWidgets help](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxbitmap.html#wxbitmapconverttoimage)) and then use the [rotate](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Image-class.html#Rotate) function ([wxWidgets help](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wximage.html#wximagerotate)).  You could then (if necessary) convert it back with [ConvertToBitmap](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Image-class.html#ConvertToBitmap) ([wxWidgets help](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wximage.html#wximageconverttobitmap)).

I couldn't see an obvious function that could be used to apply a [coordinate transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to the drawing context (DC), but there may be one in there somewhere...

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Better way would be to use Graphics context if you want a generic rotation e.g. rotate bitmap or text or any other drawing path

```
gc = wx.GCDC(dc)
gc.Rotate(angle)
gc.DrawText("anurag", 100, 100)
```

Comment: It sounded promising, but GCDC doesn't seem to have a `Rotate` method!

Comment: which version and platform you are using?
wxPython doc says it does have Rotate
and I do use it heavily
http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.GraphicsContext-class.html#Rotate

Comment: I'm confused. Check this out: http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.GCDC-class.html
What's the connection between GraphicsContext and GCDC?

Comment: Replace the first line by `gc = wx.GraphicsContext.Create(dc)`